# Can the [charset] and [character-set] tags be made synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The [charset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/charset) tag and the [character-set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/character-set) refer to the same thing. One is simply the abbreviation. I don't see any reason for them to be seperate. Can they be made synonyms, please?